# Is applicationDidBecomeActive called in every app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak

I'm making a jailbreak tweak for my iOS device and have run into a problem regarding application bundleIDs and multitasking.

I currently have it set up so that when an application icon is tapped, it grabs the application ID and stores it for later.  I needed to get this for multitasking so I tried applicationDidBecomeActive with no luck as it was never called when I thought it would be.  Is there any way to tell when an application loads from multitasking and/or app switching?

Comment: "it was never called when I thought it should be" -- is there any chance that the delegate object you expect to get called is somehow not the actual application delegate?

Comment: @stevesliva it could be that using UIApplicationDelegate won't apply to all applications...

Answer (score 0):

You can register notification in your viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(selectorYouWant)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: Since it's not an application would I hook viewDidLoad and then try it?

Comment: Nah, just try to fire it up in your init method.

Comment: The selector isn't called when a new application is active (as before)

Answer (score 0):

[Here are all the UIApplicationDelegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillEnterForeground%3a) that may be called. Upon first launch `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` will be called when initially loading the app when it is launching for the first time/is no longer in memory. As for becoming active while still in memory I would recommend you use `applicationWillEnterForeground:`.

Comment: I've tried this but it resulted in returning "com.apple.springboard" because the application is not fully loaded at this state.